# How if condition and clear the entry works in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
def Input(PIn , BIn , AIn) :
    if (PIn ==0) and (BIn ==0) and (AIn == 0)  :
         print ("ok")

    else :
         str(PIn)
         int(BIn)
         int(AIn)
         global n
         proc.append([PIn , BIn , AIn ])
         n+=1
         PIn.delete(0,END)
         BIn.delete(0,END)
         AIn.delete(0,END)
         print(proc , n)
```

I am trying to convert my python CODE to GUI but I have two problems. The first one is the if-statement is not working so if the user has entered 0 for all variables it will go to the else. the second one is that I can not clear the entry.

Comment: Where do you run `Input`?  Have you confirmed PIn, BIn, and AIn are all integers?  As a reminder, `"0" =/= 0`.  Alos, in the `else` statement, PIn is set to str and the other two are set to int.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit/ get a value from the Entry widget of tkinter you need to use

tkinter.StringVar()

```py
PIn_text_var = StringVar() 
PIn = Entry(root, textvariable=PIn_text_var)

#To edit the widget's text : 

PIn_text_var.set("new value") 

#To get the widgets text :

s = PIn_text_var.get()
print(s) 
# output : 'new value'
```

If you want to clear the Entry widget's
text :

```py
PIn_text_var.set("")
```

So as for your example :

```py
PIn_text_var = tkinter.StringVar() 
BIn_text_var = tkinter.StringVar() 
AIn_text_var = tkinter.StringVar()

proc = []
n = 0 

def Input () :
    global n

    P = PIn_text_var.get()
    B = BIn_text_var.get()
    A = AIn_text_var.get() 

    if (P=="0") and (B=="0") and (A=="0") : 
        print ("ok") 

    else : 
        temp_var_p = P
        temp_var_b = int(B)
        temp_var_a = int(A)

        proc.append([temp_var_p, temp_var_b, temp_var_a ]) 

        PIn_text_var.set("")
        BIn_text_var.set("")
        AIn_text_var.set("")
        n+=1
        print(proc , n)
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use `StringVar`. You can, but more often than not it's just extra overhead that doesn't add any real value. The widget itself has methods for getting and setting the values.

Answer (score 0):

On your first issue, typically TKinter entry widgets will pass the values through as strings. It's difficult to say with certainty since you haven't provided sample code for PIn, BIn, AIn variables, but it is likely you are comparing a string to an integer, which will evaluate to false.

Try replacing the `if` statement with either `if (PIn == "0") and (BIn == "0") and (AIn == "0"):` (which will compare strings with strings), or with `if (int(PIn) == 0) and (intBIn) == 0) and (int(AIn) == 0):` (which will compare integers with integers).

On your second point I think you will need to provide more detail on what kind of widgets PIn, BIn and AIn are.

Comment: PIn, BIn and AIn are Entries such that 

 ||   AIn = tk.Entry(frame , bg= 'white' , fg = 'black' )
AIn.place(relx= .35 , rely = 0.6 ,relwidth = 0.30 , relheight = 0.05) ||

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing the widget itself to a value. The widget is not the same thing as the value. You must first get the value from the widget before you can compare it to anything.

Since the `get` method of an entry will return a string, I recommend comparing against strings. The other option is to convert the value to an integer before comparing, though in that case you have to be prepared to handle the case where the user enters something that can't be converted to an integer.

```
if (PIn.get() == "0") and (BIn.get() == "0") and (AIn.get() == "0") ...
```